# Wondering about why a question got closed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, homework, reopen-closed

I was wondering about the reason that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439918/consider-the-following-unrealistic-investment-issue/9439998) got closed.

The stated reason is that:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is
>   ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot
>   be reasonably answered in its current form.

But I do not think that's the case -- actually, it is a well-defined question about the fractional knapsack problem.

The only remark which could be done is that it "smells" a bit of homework, but that's all.

What should I do about it? Vote to re-open it? I don't think I have the necessary reputation, should I add a comment instead?

Thanks!

Comment: You already answered the question, so it's not really clear what more were you hoping for. If actually you think the question is salvageable, given an understanding you already possess of the topic/domain, consider suggesting an edit.

Comment: Well, I am hoping to understand how the community works and what the rules for closing questions are. :-) Unfortunately, I still don't understand why that question was closed -- what is the problem with it?

Comment: Why was *this* question downvoted? I thought it was the kind of questions to be asked on meta, but since it's my very first question please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Votes on meta work differently. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences In this case it's most likely a vote for "I don't agree with you that this shouldn't have been closed".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a real question, but not the OP's question. This is merely a straight dump of what is most likely his homework problem. The OP does not seem to ask a question about it, but merely drops it on us and probably hopes we'll answer it for him.

As such I would also have said "Not a real question", because the OP simply isn't asking one. Nor has he put any effort into it for as far as we can see.

Comment: I understand your point. Also, the fact that the OP did not clearly state that it was homework definitely sounds "fishy".  Now, since I'm trying to learn to be a better member of the community, do you think it would be a good think to "salvage" the question, i.e. making it clear that it is homework, and making it clear that the OP would like a hint towards its solution?

Comment: I would say, no. Especially with homework questions I think that there is first of all an effort required by the OP. If he would have said "This is the question I'm dealing with and this is my solution, but I'm unsure about it", then he would have had a case. Just posting your homework questions for hints is not a constructive approach. In this case I would like to see the OP salvage the question (if possible) and not an outsider. Just my opinion though.